# Restriction on down voting the post for new users whose reputation is <100

Tags: feature-request

I feel any user who is new to this site will definitely not know of all the features, rules & regulations in a first Go while posting their question.

So it's better to remove the feature of down voting the post where the user reputation is <100. Why less than 100, because by the time user earns 100 reputation points, I feel the user will get familiar with the rules & regulations while asking a question and that way, they don't feel the negativity on the site and use the site for the best use of technology.

All this observation I put based out of my experience with the site.

Comment: "All this observation I put based out of my experience with the site." Out of interest, when you were asking your first question, how much of the "How to ask" page did you read? There's *plenty* of information available for users who understand that when they're asked to comply with the rules and conventions of a site, it's worth researching what those are before rushing headlong into things.

Comment: To be frank, I haven't read all those things at all while asking my first question. It's only in the later time I have learnt and started to articulate in asking questions.

Comment: In that case, I have relatively little sympathy - and I'd suggest that basically making new users' questions immune from criticism in the form of downvoting would simply encourage that sort of poor behavior. A more constructive suggestion might be that if a user with a rep under 100 ends up with a negative overall score for a question, that they be explicitly directed to read those documents.

Comment: New users often don't read the how to ask page, so your plan is to... remove the encouragement (the downvotes) that new users have to help them desire to read the how to ask page?

Comment: 'So it's better' ... better for whom?  Better for the new [ab]users who could not be bothred to read the poicy/rules/guidelines and just posted their superdupe, too broad and unclear homework dump anyway?  How is it better for the skilled and experienced SO users who continually have to handle the bad questions?  No, disagree, (again, again).

Comment: "Sorry your honour, I didn't know murder was illegal, it's my first time visiting here, I guess I should've read the laws a bit in retrospect" we shouldn't appease people who are ignorant enough to not read the rules of the site, especially when they're warned when they first post.

Comment: @George I disagree to your sarcasm in comparing Murder equals to Posting a question in SO

Comment: It's a metaphor;  ignorance of the rules is no excuse.

Comment: @MartinJames better and convenience of the user interests and of course with in a certain limit

Comment: @DavyM Are you serious? None of the down votes has encouraged me to look back at my question. It's my necessity to seek answer that made me to look into the guidelines.

Comment: @mannedear Murder != posting on SO obviously, but some of the questions that get posted are such low quality you'd think it'd be as obvious as being off topic as murder being illegal. Moving on from the metaphor (and my bad attempt at humour), isn't downvoting and pointing to the FAQ and help section the best way for new users to understand what's the expected quality on this site?

Comment: Then there's the problem of identifying real  'new users'.  Is a new user 'I misread the rules and asked a question that was not well received, I must be more careful in future', or 'I don't care about any rules, so why read them?  I open a new account for every question and just copypaste in my homework.  Sure, some of my questions are closed before I get an answer to copy out, some of my accounts get deleted but, overall, I do get some answers from the drones and get to spend more time in the bar than those other naive morons with scruples in my class, and I get better marks, win-win!'.

Comment: Please don't edit your question into something different which invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 21):

If we did this, we'd never get rid of the accounts who believe it's fine to:

- POST THEIR TITLE IN ALL CAPS
- Say that they need "urgent" help and insist that we drop whatever it is we're doing to help them
- Just ask incredibly broad questions outright

I get that you don't like being downvoted, and I get that the reasons for it can be arcane.  It's important to not take it personal and instead look at what you can do to improve your question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Ok, out of curiosity, what does it mean to down vote the OP post here? Is that means users don't like the suggestion mentioned in the post? or any thing else ??

Comment: @mannedear: Yes, downvoting on Meta often/usually means disagreement.

Comment: @mannedear Or that you've done absolutely no research since this idea gets suggested a lot and shot down a lot too.

Comment: @RobertLongson you yourself quoting this idea getting suggested a lot and so why not Admin take a clue and implement this for a limited period and see how it goes. There's nothing wrong in trying some thing where more users are suggesting IMO.

Comment: Because it's a completely stupid idea based on fallacious assumptions. Why would Admins develop something that the community downvotes every time, why wouldn't they instead spend their time on things that the community indicates they actually want?

Comment: @mannedear it doesn't matter if the same idea is suggested a million times - they are all duplicates, but continually posted because either the posters did not bother to check for dupes, or don't care about them anyway.  Contrary arguments, or for actually rasing the bar for new users, have also been posted, but generally by the experienced and responsible users who deal with so many bad questions, and they tend to not post so many obvious and continual duplicates on meta.  If any set of users are suffering from negativity, it's the skilled and experienced developers who answer good questions.

Comment: @RobertLongson stupid idea?, how did you even conclude it this way, based out of few down votes? If yes, those down votes hardly count to less than 1% of total community member I strongly feel. No use of endless debates as everyone has their own thought process and I'm open to voting on this down voting of new users and it clears what is what. 

Admin, are you seeing this?

Comment: Based on the dozens of times I've seen this question (or a very similar variant of it) asked and the carefully considered answers to a number of those questions explaining why it's a bad idea.

Comment: @MartinJames Firstly, if an idea suggested a million times, not considered is an act of negligence. 
Secondly, this question is viewed 55 times and only 24 of them down voted as they don't liked the suggestion which is less than 50%, actually it's 44%. Only 11 out of 55 users considered this answer useful which amounts to 20%. And the remaining 80% of the users have a different opinion or idea about my suggestion. So, as I said earlier, the idea of voting on this suggestion will clear everyone's clouds. What say?

Comment: Well, I'm sorely tempted to aks a feature-request meta question myself, say.. 'Restriction on upvoting on questions for new users whose reputation is <100'.  That would direct new usiers into editing or answering questions before gaining the right to ask them, forcing them to gain experience. learn the rules/policy, greatly reducing spam, timewasters with super-dupes, homework dumps, sock puppets, voting-rings, 'Programming 101' incompetents and a huge chunk of other abusers.

Comment: I don't ask such questions because I know that all such measures have already been suggested at least once and I would be heavily downvoted.

Comment: @mannedear The view count isn't unique viewers, so that calculation is completely off. As MartinJames has said, this question/request has been asked multiple time and has always been heavily downvoted/shown disagreement.

Comment: @mannedear Your idea isn't stupid because it has several dozen downvotes.  It has several dozen downvotes because it's stupid.  The comments on your post explaining why it would be harmful to implement are the reason it's a stupid idea.  You can't talk about how the idea isn't being considered when you've gotten *tons* of people explaining to you why it's a bad idea.  Clearly they've considered it,and explained why it's a bad idea.  "Considering" an idea doesn't mean agreeing with it.  If your post had no votes, no comments, and no feedback at all, *that* would be people not considering it.

Comment: @Servy that's a long way to explain Servy. Any ways thanks to all for taking time in addressing my request, doable or not doable is completely a different thing. For now, we can go with what Admin has put up with the rule and guess what, I also need to follow nonetheless

Comment: @mannedear I wasn't talking about whether or not it's doable.  I was saying that it's a terrible idea and we wouldn't *want* to do it, not that we *couldn't*.  But yes, you are also obligated to follow the rules, that's true.